# Capitalizing the suffix "-like"

Tags: punctuation, capitalization

Should I capitalize the suffix *-like* in a title if it is hyphenated?

For example:

**Diamond-Like Carbon Coating** or **Diamond-like Carbon Coating**

**Metal-Like Compounds** or **Metal-like Compounds**

Which is correct?

Comment: I wouldn't. A capital after a hyphen is not customary, except in the case of a double-barrelled personal name that is hyphenated.

Comment: No, no caps there.

Comment: This was asked on [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460/do-you-capitalize-both-parts-of-a-hyphenated-word-in-a-title) and there's no firm rule (unless you have a style guide that says otherwise): often capitalizing looks better, but it depends how significant the second part is.

Answer (score -1):

Precisely *because* 'like' is a hyphenated suffix, it should not be capitalized in a title.

Source: *AMA Manual of Style* (online and behind a paywall)